# How to change the border height of an unfilled or partially filled ft.TextField?

Tags: python, flet

How to change the border height of an unfilled or partially filled ft.TextField?

How to set fixed size of field borders. In the current implementation with the width=400 parameter it sets the maximum values of the element size. But the borders change dynamically, depending on the filled text. I want the borders to be static c initially with set size=width.
Video demonstration:

> https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/105080268/283751675-26162ef5-6f3e-4050-9cdd-59d52e1ffadd.mov

`entry_message = ft.TextField(label="Message", multiline=True, expand=False, width=400, height=200)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you really want to do. You want the multi-line text field to have a fixed size? If so you can just put a very large number in parameters `min_lines` and `max_lines`, like the following:

```py
import flet as ft

def main(page: ft.Page):
    width = 400
    entry_message = ft.TextField(
        label="Message",
        multiline=True,
        min_lines=10000,
        max_lines=10000,
        width=width,
        height=200,
    )
    recipient = ft.TextField(label="Recipient Name", expand=1)
    chat = ft.TextField(label="Chat ID", expand=1)
    row = ft.Row([recipient, chat], width=width)
    page.add(entry_message, row)

ft.app(target=main)
```

This will result in the following:

[image: form]